# how to insert data on mongo db through restheart api

Tags: mongodb, restheart

i am using mongo DB 3.0 version and restheart API 2.0 version. now i am trying to check my queries (URI) through postman chrome interface. and i create a database(test) table(mycol) and two documents in mongo DB, when i filter that data it shows correctly but when i try to insert data into mongodb through postman or HAL Browser it shows error, can you peoples please guide me the syntax format.

[Query for filter data, it gives correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rguhH.png)

[Query for insert a document, it shows some error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdyXS.png)

and also i need to know <docid> in the URI format : /<dbname>/<collname>/<docid>[?doc_type=TYPE] what it means <docid> please explain in detail with some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a document you need either to POST the collection `POST /test/mycol` or PUT a document `PUT /test/mycol/<docid>`

`<docid>` stands for document id. the query parameter`docid_type` is optional and allows to specify the type of the `<docid>` in the URL, more information in the documentation [Resource URI](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/ToCM) section.

For instance, if you want to create the following document `{ "_id": “mydoc", “message”: “hello” }` you do

`PUT /test/mycol/mydoc { “message”: “hello”}`

or

`POST /test/mycol { "_id": “mydoc", “message”: “hello” }`

In the latter case, if you don’t specify the _id, it will be autogenerated as an ObjectId.

Note that you have to specify the `Content-Type` request header to be either `application/json` or `application/hal+json`.

For instance, using Postman you set the body to be *raw* and select *JSON (application/json)* from the dropdown on the right. You'll notice that this will add the Content-Type header to the headers.

[image: restheart - post with postman]

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but still i have one problem when i try to insert data as you said, it will take whole query as a _id name and data is not inserting. my query http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/mycol/mydoc123/ {"name":"rsk"} i get a result from mongodb is : <"_id" : "mydoc123" , "_etag" : "76743hjghjdfg744"> but data is not insert

Answer (score 1):

You need add a header to your request: `content-type = application/json`

[image]

Look this for more info:

https://restheart.org/docs/mongodb-rest/write-docs

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem.
The problem was I used field names starting with "_"
i.e. field names like "_type", "_name".
Try to avoid such names.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems as you. For insert you should just write your object like this:

```
   {
    "code": 20,
    "name": "s",
    "family": "x"
   }
```

And set POST your method, also for update if the document exists it will be updated, otherwise it will be created.

Please look at this link for more information
https://community.boomi.com/s/article/howtointegratewithmongodbusingopensourcerestheartlibrary#jive_content_id_Scenario_1__InsertUpdate_an_Employee_record_in_Employees_collection_using_POST